# $x$ is a limit point of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\exists$ a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ so that $x$ is a limit point of $\{x_i\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

PROBLEM: $x$ is a limit point of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\exists$ a sequence of points $\{x_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $x_i \in A$ so that $x$ is a limit point of $\{x_i\}$.

My attempt: If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $x$ must contain points of $A$. Put $N = D^n(x, \frac{1}{k})$ for $k \geq 1$. Notice, this disc must contain points of $A$. Let $x_k \in D^n(x, \frac{1}{k}) \cap A$ for all $k$. This gives us a sequence of points from $A$. For any disc $D^n(x,r)$, we can select an integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < r$. This follows from the archimidean property. Notice that $D^n(x,r) \supseteq D^n(x,\frac{1}{N}) \supseteq D^n(x, \frac{1}{N+1}) \supseteq .... $ Therefore, we have

$$ x_N, x_{N+1}, x_{N+2}, .... \in D^n(x, \frac{1}{N}) \subseteq D^n(x,r)$$

Notice by the nested set property, $x$ must be the only limit point of the sequence constructed.

Conversely, Suppose $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence where each $x_i \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x$ is a limit point of the sequence $\{x_i\}$. We show $x$ is also a limit point of the set $A$. Since $x$ is a limit point of the sequence, then, by definition we have that every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinite number of the $x_i's$. But, since the $x_i \in A$, then by definition $x$ is also a limit point of the set $A$ since every neighborhood $N$ of $x$ contain at least one point of $A$.

Is this proof correct? any feedback? thanks

Comment: In the second half, you are assuming $x\in A$?

Comment: you mean in the reverse direction? $x$ not in $A$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. It's a little clumsily formulated, showing that you're not yet experienced in the matter, but that's no problem at all. With a bit more experience you will start to streamline the proofs yourself. ("Notice, this disc must contain points of $A$." Depending on circumstances, that can be considered obvious, or you can say "$N\cap A \neq \varnothing$ since $x \in \overline{A}$". "Notice by the nested set property, $x$ must be the only limit point of the sequence constructed." Good observation, but irrelevant for the task, can be omitted.)

Comment: The result is not stated quite correctly, and there are corresponding problems in the proofs. The points in the sequence should be distinct. Now in the proof, when you are choosing $x_k$, you don't want it to be $x$. Same easily fixed issue in the reverse direction.

Comment: Please give your questions more descriptive titles. People who are searching the site need to be able to see what a question is about from its title.